# How to resize an image but maintain pixel values in sk-image?

Tags: python, scipy, resize, scikit-image

I want to resize images. My images contain specific values [0, 1, 2, 7, 9]. After resizing, new values are introduced like 5 and whatnot. I want to prevent that.

I'm currently using `scikit` image resize function. I've tried all interpolation flags but to no avail.

EDIT: a simple code to show the problem

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.transform import resize
vals = [0, 1, 4, 6]
N, M = 100, 100
image = np.random.choice(vals, N * M).reshape(N, M).astype('uint8')
resized_image = resize(image, (50, 50), preserve_range=True).astype('uint8')

print('vals before resizing ', np.unique(image))
print('vals after resizing ', np.unique(resized_image))
```

Comment: I guess if you want to retain original pixel values, result image will have aliasing.

Comment: @SaeedMasoomi yeah I don't mind that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `anti_aliasing` to `False`:

```
resized_image = resize(image, (50, 50), order=0, preserve_range=True, anti_aliasing=False).astype('uint8')
```

> anti_aliasingbool, optional
>   Whether to apply a Gaussian filter to smooth the image prior to down-scaling. It is crucial to filter when down-sampling the image to avoid aliasing artifacts.

The aliasing filter applies Gaussian filter, that produces new values.

---

Result:

```
vals before resizing  [0 1 4 6]
vals after resizing  [0 1 4 6]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid introducing new values, you need to avoid linear, bi-linear, quadratic and other *"calculated"* types of interpolation and use NEAREST_NEIGHBOUR interpolation. This is especially important with palette (i.e. indexed) images and classification images where each number represents a class, which could mean that interpolating between a class that represents, say, "forest" and an adjacent class that represents "highway" suddenly introduces some new value between the two that means you have constructed a beach in Arizona!

That means, use `order=0` (corresponding to *"nearest neighbour"*) rather than the default `order=1` (corresponding to *"bilinear"*) when resizing.

The various types of interpolation are expounded [here](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.warp).

Comment: I've gone ahead and put order=0, still new values are introduced.

Comment: Kindly show a **Minimum Complete Verifiable Example* of your code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and I'll take a look and see what I can see :-)

Comment: I've gone ahead and added a simple code showing the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I am about to go offline, but have a read here about `astype()` https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/user_guide/data_types.html and `preserve_range` later on same page.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want anti-aliasing, but the resize function will apply it by default,(so the function will apply a Gaussian kernel on image to get rid off aliasing) so if you want to retain original pixels you must disable this flag by `anti_aliasing=False`

```
resized_image = resize(image, (50, 50), preserve_range=True, anti_aliasing=False,order=0).astype('uint8')
```

By this change the output will be:

```
vals before resizing  [0 1 4 6]
vals after resizing  [0 1 4 6]
```

By looking at the resize function documentation, we can see that Gaussian kernel will apply only when your resized image is smaller than original one.(which is your case)

> anti_aliasingbool, optional
>
> Whether to apply a Gaussian filter to smooth the image prior to
>   down-scaling. It is crucial to filter when down-sampling the image to
>   avoid aliasing artifacts.

Comment: "Gaussian kernel will apply only when your resized image is smaller than original one" that statement is incorrect.